# Interação entre Threads no Python, mensagem de erro " object is not callable"?

Tags: python, thread, multithreading

Estou fazendo a interação de 4 Threads, porém ao executá-las ao mesmo tempo aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> object is not callable

Ou seja, o objeto não pode ser chamado. Como corrigi-lo?

Segue abaixo o código.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_1 = 1
Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_2 = 1
Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_3 = 1
Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_4 = 1

def Thread_Via_1():
    print("Via 1 - Verde")
    Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_1 = Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_1 + 1
    print("Carro ", Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_1)
    time.sleep(1)

def Thread_Via_2():
    print("Via 2 - Verde")
    print("Carro ", Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_2)
    Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_2 = Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_2 + 1
    time.sleep(1)

def Thread_Via_3():
    print("Via 3 - Verde")
    print("Carro ", Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_3)
    Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_3 = Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_3 + 1
    time.sleep(1)

def Thread_Via_4():
    print("Via 4 - Verde")
    print("Carro ", Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_4)
    Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_4 = Contador_De_Carros_Da_via_4 + 1
    time.sleep(1)

x = 4

while x > 0:    
    Thread_Via_1 = Thread(target=Thread_Via_1,args=[5])
    Thread_Via_1.start()
    Thread_Via_2 = Thread(target=Thread_Via_2,args=[5])    
    Thread_Via_2.start()
    Thread_Via_3 = Thread(target=Thread_Via_3,args=[5])
    Thread_Via_3.start()
    Thread_Via_4 = Thread(target=Thread_Via_4,args=[5])
    Thread_Via_4.start()
    x = x - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao fazer `Thread_Via_N = Thread(...)` a variável com aquele nome passa a ser o objeto retornado pela função `Thread`, em vez disso, use outra variável:

```
x = 4
while x > 0:    
    tmp = Thread(target=Thread_Via_1,args=[5])
    tmp.start()
    tmp = Thread(target=Thread_Via_2,args=[5])    
    tmp.start()
    # ...
    x = x - 1
```

Ou chame o `start` diretamente, caso não precise manter o objeto salvo

```
x = 4
while x > 0:    
    Thread(target=Thread_Via_1,args=[5]).start()
    Thread(target=Thread_Via_2,args=[5]).start()
    # ...
    x = x - 1
```

Comment: Cara resolveu o problema, porem a execução de minhas 4 threads estão desorganizadas! de qualquer forma eu agradeço pois resolveu o problema.

Comment: Cara, eu precisei fazer da segunda forma que vc falou, colocando o .start() na frente,porem ele só executa uma vez mesmo estando em um laço com mais de uma execução.